# How to solve this problem, the media slide layer appears in the Create pop-up

Tags: javascript

the media slide layer appears in the Create pop-up, it should appear in the frontmost layer in the Create section

Code media slide:

{{-- HEADER --}}

{{-- ALl MEDIA --}}

```
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="javascript:void()"
                onclick="forMediaModal('{{ route('media.create') }}', 'Unggah Media')"
                class="btn-sm btn-primary ml-2 text-white text-center">Upload Media <i
                    class="fa fa-cloud-upload ml-2" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <a href="#!" data-url="{{ route('media.filter', 'all') }}" data-value="all"
                    onclick="filterMedia(this)" class="all_media p-3">All Media</a>
                @if (Auth::user()->user_type == 'Admin')
                    <a href="#!" data-url="{{ route('media.filter', 'category') }}" data-value="category"
                        onclick="filterMedia(this)" class="category_media p-3">Category</a>
                    <a href="#!" data-url="{{ route('media.filter', 'slider') }}" data-value="slider"
                        onclick="filterMedia(this)" class="slider_media p-3">Slider</a>
                    <a href="#!" data-url="{{ route('media.filter', 'organization') }}" data-value="organization"
                        onclick="filterMedia(this)" class="organizer_media p-3">Organization</a>
                    <a href="#!" data-url="{{ route('media.filter', 'package') }}" data-value="package"
                        onclick="filterMedia(this)" class="package_media p-3">Package</a>
                @endif
                <a href="#!" data-url="{{ route('media.filter', 'source_code') }}" data-value="source_code"
                    onclick="filterMedia(this)" class="source_code_media p-3">Source Code</a>
                <a href="#!" data-url="{{ route('media.filter', 'thumbnail') }}" data-value="thumbnail"
                    onclick="filterMedia(this)" class="thumbnail_media p-3">Thumbnail</a>
                <a href="#!" data-url="{{ route('media.filter', 'file') }}" data-value="file"
                    onclick="filterMedia(this)" class="file_media p-3">File</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- masonary -->
<div class="container-fluid mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="row media_row">
        @forelse ($medias as $media)
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xl-3 mb-3 myTable">



                <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="getImage(this)" data-image="{{ $media->image }}"
                    class="media_select shadow-sm rounded">
                    <div class="card m-2">
                        @if ($media->alt == 'image')
                            <img class="card-img" src="{{ filePath($media->image) }}"
                                alt="{{ $media->alt }}">
                        @endif
                        @if ($media->alt == 'pdf')
                            <img class="card-img w-50 m-auto" src="{{ filePath('pdf.png') }}"
                                alt="{{ $media->alt }}">
                        @endif
                        @if ($media->alt == 'zip')
                            <img class="card-img rounded w-50 m-auto" src="{{ filePath('zip.png') }}"
                                alt="{{ $media->alt }}">
                        @endif
                        @if ($media->alt == 'video')
                            <video controls crossorigin playsinline id="player" class="w-100"
                                src="{{ filePath($media->image) }}"></video>
                        @endif
                        <span class="text-center text-dark">{{ $media->title }}</span>
                    </div>
                </a>



            </div>

        @empty

            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <img src="{{ filePath('media-not-found.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="#media not found">
            </div>
        @endforelse
    </div>
</div>
<!-- masonary:END -->
{{-- ALl MEDIA::END --}}

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".myInput").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $(".myTable").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7lFe.png) this img problem, I hope the slide appears in front of the pop up create.`

I have tried various ways that occurred to me, but I have not found a solution to this

Comment: This project is using Bootstrap and jQuery, is that correct? Is there any other CSS in this project that might affect things? Have you provided code for the  Create pop-up, I can't spot it?

Comment: If I assume that Create pop-up is also a modal, does it make any difference which one appears first in the page markup?

Answer (score 1):

If I look [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#toggle-between-modals) in the Bootstrap docs it says:

> Please note multiple modals cannot be open at the same time

Does the trick described by that link above, where you can toggle between modals, help at all?

> Toggle between multiple modals with some clever placement of the data-bs-target and data-bs-toggle attributes.

> Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set data-bs-toggle="modal" on a controller element, like a button, along with a data-bs-target="#foo" or href="#foo" to target a specific modal to toggle.